# Capistrano deploys to 'current' folder- how to make it my 'root' folder

Tags: capistrano

Using capistrano I am successfully deploying code to my server btu it goes into a 'current' directory. How do I then set up my server to use this current folder as its root so the website loads when I visit the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just a case of modifying the host settings on the server and setting the root directory there to point to the current release directory.